# Limit number of simultaneous user sessions in amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a react app that uses amplify for authentication. I want to restrict the maximum number of devices a user can login simultaneously to three. How can I do that using amplify?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly doesn't work. Please share some code, concept you already have. SO requires questions to be very specific. As it currently is - your is not.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito is not a session handling service, you'll be creating a lot of problems trying to build this only with cognito. The stateless auth pattern cognito encourages is quite contrary to stateful sessions you are trying to implement.

I would suggest instead that after authenticating with Cognito, you use the token to initiate a session in your own service. It could be implemented simply in a custom Lambda backed by DynamoDB.